# GitBash cmd line branch delete

Tags: git-branch, git-bash

what does it mean that I see `(feature/StoreTextVariable_134)` (I assume branch I created earlier in and switched to in VS, and I deleted the local code earlier)?

how can I get rid of it?

[image]

I'm a GitBash newbie.

Answer (score 1):

> what does it mean that I see (feature/StoreTextVariable_134)

**feature/StoreTextVariable_134** is the branch of git that you are currently working on.

Type **git branch** to check how many branches in your source code.

> how can I get rid of it?

Use **git checkout**  to move to the branch you need to work with.

[output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/b5wL0.png)

Note: If there is a change in source code on the current branch then you need to commit before switching branches.

Please refer more detail here:
[Git document](https://git-scm.com/docs)

Answer (score 1):

Thanks @Tai I had to use `-f` with my checkout so that I could discard pending changes I didn't need

`git checkout -f branchName`

then to delete it I used

`git branch -d -f branchName`

now I am back on my default branch